# Bias variance tradeoff in Gaussian process regression

Tags: gaussian-process, bias-variance-tradeoff

Can someone explain in simple terms the bias and variance tradeoff of Gaussian Process regression?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not *exactly* what you asked, Rasmussen and Williams talk about (essentially) this briefly in [chapter 5](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf) of *Gaussian Processes for machine learning*.

In particular:

> Notice that the trade-off between data-fit and model complexity is automatic;
> there is no need to set a parameter externally to fix the trade-off.

For a mathematical explanation of *how* this occurs, you can check out the "interpretation" paragraph (in subsection 5.4.1) on page 113 of the same chapter, though the whole of chapter 5 would probably be useful reading.

A *very* brief summary is that the likelihood function contains two terms: one encouraging "a good fit for the data" (Rasmussen and Williams call this the "data fit" term), and one penalising complexity (the "complexity penalty").